# Too much of a space between columns in html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am having issue with my html/css table. If you look at the screenshots below, the table within the small screen is perfect (ignore the borders). It's perfect in regards to the space between the text and audio player.

When you look at the wider screen, the gap is too big between the text and the audio player. So my question is how to rectify this? I know I can set smaller width to the first column but that might not be good idea if screen is too small that it causes the text to break over two lines. It's like I want it to close the gap in big screen but be keep the same feature it's doing currently when the screen shrinks in size.

[image]

[image: mns]

```
<table style="width: 50%; table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: normal;">
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Call 1</strong></td>
      <td>
        <audio
        controls
        src="aud/1 (no filter).mp3">
            Your browser does not support the
            <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>
      </td>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
table { border:1px solid #ccc;}
audio { width:100%;}
td { width:50%;}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: normal;">
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Call 1</strong></td>
      <td>
        <audio
        controls
        src="aud/1 (no filter).mp3">
            Your browser does not support the
            <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>
      </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, similar to how I have it anyway but mine is 50% table and then 25%

Comment: please add css {display: inline-table;} for td

Answer (score 1):

> I know I can set smaller width to the first column but that might not
>   be good idea if screen is too small that it causes the text to break
>   over two lines.

One approach is to give your text a `font-size` relative to the width of the viewport.

The perfect unit for this is `vw` - the viewport width unit.

`1vw` is equal to 1% of the viewport width.

So here, for example, you could style a number of your `<td>` properties all using `vw`, like this:

```
  height: 2vw;
  padding: 2vw;
  line-height: 4vw;
  font-size: 4vw;
```

Then, when the viewport widens and narrows, the height of the `<td>` and the size of the `font` will grow and shrink, relative to the viewport.

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(25, 33, 44);
}

table {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid rgb(223, 89, 67);
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  height: 2vw;
  padding: 2vw;
  line-height: 4vw;
  font-size: 4vw;
  border: 1px solid rgb(223, 89, 67);
}

audio {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td><strong>Call 1</strong></td>
<td>
<audio controls src="aud/1 (no filter).mp3">
Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `table width` is causing problem here. You can either give width in smaller percentage or give width in `pixels`so the width will be same on smaller and bigger screens. Remember that width in percentage acts according to the size of screen.

See the example below in which i've added width of table in `fixed pixels`:
[CODEPEN EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/iahmadhabibx/pen/jOPBmeq)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `column-width: auto;` for the CSS code of the first column, it will provide the necessary width space for the longest string in the first column. Then you can add a `padding-right` if you want a space from the elements and the rigth border.

```html
<table style="width: 50%; table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: normal;" border="1" border-collapse="collapse">
    <tr>
      <td style="column-width: auto; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 20px"><strong>Call 1</strong></td>
      <td>
        <audio
        controls
        src="aud/1 (no filter).mp3">
            Your browser does not support the
            <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>
      </td>
```

Hope this answer can help you.